# Show MP3 Files in ListViews at Android

Tags: android, listview, mp3, sd-card

I'm a beginner in android programming.
I wanted to make a simple listview that listing all mp3 files from SD Card. I've tried a lot of sample code, but not all of them working completely. Help will be appriciated.

```
public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv;
//Songs List
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //ArrayList<String> songsListData = new ArrayList<>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    for(int i=0; i < songsList.size();i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String [] {"songTitle"},new int[] {
            R.id.songTitle});
    //setListAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //ListView lv = getListView();

}
}
```

And here is the SongsManager Class

```
public class SongsManager {
//SDCARD
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern=".mp3";
//Constructor
public SongsManager(){

}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> getPlayList(){
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH !=null){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if(listFiles != null && listFiles.length>0){
            for(File file:listFiles){
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()){
                    scanDirectory(file);
                }else{
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return songsList;
}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    if(directory != null){
        File[]listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if(listFiles != null && listFiles.length>0){
            for (File file : listFiles){
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    scanDirectory(file);
                }else{
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if(song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)){
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String ,String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle",song.getName().substring(0,(song.getName().length()-4)));
        songMap.put("songPath",song.getPath());

        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}

class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
}
```

it gives error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a45v.praransemen/com.example.a45v.praransemen.PlayListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.a45v.praransemen.PlayListActivity.onCreate(PlayListActivity.java:41)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the playlist.XML

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

and here is the playlist_item.XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/songTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "not all of them working completely" means.

Comment: ive tried a lot of code from same case like me, but it seems not all of the code are working anymore. But, when i read the comment section from user who also tried the code, they said that it works completely fine. Thats what i mean.

Comment: We cannot help you with problems in your code unless **you explain what those problems are**.

Comment: ah my bad, when i try the program, it keeps giving me a crash
the errors say:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Next time, please put all the info in your post, including the log error. With all these you will have more chances to get a proper answer

Comment: ive listed an important error log(i guessed) from the android monitor
thx for the respond. Please guide me if there's something that i need to listed again

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `res/layout/playlist.xml` does not contain a `ListView` with an `android:id` value of `@android:id/list`.

Comment: I've changed it, and it run with a blank white screen
maybe something wrong with the directory fetching?

Comment: @GioVanno: Step through your code in the debugger, and see whether you are putting anything into the `ListAdapter`.

Comment: from the list adapter:
savedinstanceState=null
songsListData size=0
plm=SongsManager

Comment: @GioVanno: If `songsList` is empty, you will get an empty list. It will be faster and more reliable to query the `MediaStore` provider for all MP3 content.

Comment: sounds new to me
ill give it a try for MediaStore 
Thanks a lot for ur guidance, it really helps me :)
ill post it later

Comment: Hello There,
ive managed to use media store tutorial from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704297/filter-mp3-files-from-other-media-files-using-mediastore-mediametadataretrieve

ive changed the entire SongsManager class with the one from the answered solution, but it gives me this error

cannot find symbol method getContentResolver()

maybe there's something that i missed?

Comment: @GioVanno: `getContentResolver()` is a method on `Context`, and so it is available from subclasses of `Context` like `Activity`.

Comment: ah i see
The codes work perfectly while im moving those code, thank you for ur help!
much obliged :)